# Boolean type has some error to render the page, in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a domain class named `DaySchedule` like this:

```
 class DaySchedule {
        Date Todaysdate
        String startTime;
        String endTime;
        String task
        int priority 
        boolean completed
}
```

I have defined a controller for this domain class :

```
def allcompletedtask = {
        def completedtask = new DaySchedule(completed:true)
        def completedwork = DaySchedule.findAll(completedtask)
        [ completedwork : completedwork ]
    }
```

(To find the list of completed task)

For rendering it, I have a view file like this :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> 
            Completed Task.
        </title>
        <meta name ="layout" content="main" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2> All these are the completed task </h2>
        <g:each in="${completedwork}" var="completedtask">
            <div id = "todayswork" >
                ${completedtask.task} completed by
                ${completedtask.schedule.user.login}
            </div>
        </g:each>       
    </body>
</html>
```

I have some table inserted via `BootStrap` file. In which I have defined some as `completed` and some as not `completed` via setting `true` and `false` respectively.

But the problem is, while rendering(that is when viewing in browser), I'm getting the output only as this :

[image]

And the output screen suggests that these lines from the view file have not rendered :

```
<div id = "todayswork" >
        ${completedtask.task} completed by
        ${completedtask.schedule.user.login}
</div>
```

No errors have shown, where I went wrong? Whats happening behind the scenes?

### Edit:

I found out the problem is with `boolean` type in Domain class `DaySchedule`. If I change that to `String` and use `"yes"` in place of `true`. I get what I need. But why `boolean` is not working properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before debugging the view, I would check if the controller was outputting the expected model, just by adding: println("completedwork: $completedwork") before returning the model to the view. That way you would have noticed, that there is nothing wrong with your view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your completed as **boolean** - having it as a String with 'yes'/'no' is just plain clutter.

Try change your actionh to:

```
def allcompletedtask = {
    def completedwork = DaySchedule.findAllByCompleted(true)
    println completedwork // Just to check if your model is correct
    [ completedwork : completedwork ]
}
```

I see no reason why you would use query by example

Comment: ha ha.. Your thing is working. I guess there is some problem with QBE, in my example. I just said that using `yes/no` made my test pass...No way I would  use those in my application :)